# what's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with the following code?

```
   for (var x=0;x<8;x++){
      for (var y=0;y<8;y++){
        table[y][x]=new Peon("black",x,y,table);
      }
   {
```

I know that there's something wrong because if I remove it from the code bellow it works, if I leave it there it never reaches the second "alert".

```
  <HTML>
    <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Chess</TITLE>
      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      var table = [];


      function Peon(color,posX,posY,board){
        this.color=color;
        this.posX=posX;
        this.posY=posY;
        this.board=board; //reference to the game board

        this.move = function(x,y){
          /*
          board[posY][posX]=null;
          board[y][x]= this;

          posX=x;
          posY=y;
          */
          alert("x "+x+" y "+y);
        };
        this.isValidMove = function(x,y){ return false;};
        return true;
      }

      //Board Inizialization 
      for (var i=3;i<5;i++){
          table[i]=[];
      }

      for (var x=0;x<8;x++){
          for (var y=0;y<8;y++){
            table[y][x]=new Peon("black",x,y,table);
          }
      }


      var n = new Peon("black",0,0,table);


      function move(x, y) {
        alert("debug");

        n.move(x+1,y+1);
        alert("debug 2");

          //Check if there is a piece already selected
           //no Check if selection is valid
               //yes Select
               //no Do nothing
           //Click on owned piece?
               //yes Change selection if valid
               //no Is move valid?
                   //yes move/eat
                   //no Do nothing
      }


      </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

      <INPUT id="b00" TYPE="button" style="background-color:EEEEEE" Value="Click" onClick="move(0,0)">

      <div id="writeHere"></div>
    </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Comment: brackets, please! also, you call it with y,x but the constructor expects x, y

Comment: i dont get any output at all http://jsfiddle.net/JYgJC/

Comment: Thank you all, I should have seen it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about:

```
for (var i=3;i<5;i++)
      table[i]=[];
```

As it will only create new arrays at index 3 and 4.

By the way, why does you Peon function return true? It should return an instance, not true.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign an array value to an array that is not there.

When you define the "inner" array here:

```
for (var i=3;i<5;i++) {
      table[i]=[];
}
```

You create:

```
table[3]
table[4]
```

But then in this part:

```
  for (var x=0;x<8;x++) {
      for (var y=0;y<8;y++) {
        table[y][x]=new Peon("black",y,x,table);
      }
    }
```

You are trying to assign:

```
table[0]
table[1]
table[2]
table[3]
...
table[7]
```

So for the fix, I am going with 0-8, which creates a 7x7 board:
first the initialization fixes (added the multi-dimensional array fix):

```
  //Board Inizialization 

      for (var i=0;i<8;i++) {
          table[i]=[];
        }
      for (var x=0;x<8;x++) {
          for (var y=0;y<8;y++) {
            table[x].push(new Peon("black",x,y,table));
                }
        }
```

and your alert fix:

```
  function move(x, y) {
    alert("debug");

    n.move(x+1+","+y+1);
    alert("debug 2");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here,

```
  for (var i=3;i<5;i++)
      table[i]=[];


  for (var x=0;x<8;x++)
      for (var y=0;y<8;y++)
        table[y][x]=new Peon("black",y,x,table);
```

Your first loop loops from 3 to 5, but the second tries accessing `table[0][0]` which you never assigned. Change the first loop to

```
for (var i=0;i<8;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your nested for loop you call the Peon constructor like so:

```
new Peon("black",y,x,table);
```

but the Peon function expects the order to be different. X and Y are the wrong way round it seems:

```
function Peon(color,posX,posY,board
```

Answer (score 0):

You treat peon like it returns an object but all it returns is true of false.(var n = new Peon("black",0,0,table);)
later you use n.move(x+1,y+1);

Comment: `Peon()` returns true, but `new Peon()` always returns an object

Answer (score 0):

Because table is not a two-dimensional array.
JavaScript doesn't have real two-dimensional array, so you can mock with Array.
try this:

```
var table = new Array();
table[0] = new Array();
table[1] = new Array();
table[2] = new Array();
table[3] = new Array();
table[4] = new Array();
table[5] = new Array();
table[6] = new Array();
table[7] = new Array();
```